# Changing kernel driver from wl to b43

Tags: wireless, drivers, kernel, 14.10, broadcom

im running on ubuntu 14.10 and i want to change my wireless kernel driver from wl to b43. is there a step by step procedure to do this?

here's my adapter info.

i run `sudo lspci -k`

> 08:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
>   (rev 01)  Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2230  Kernel
>   driver in use: wl

i run `sudo lspci -vnn`

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2230]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at b5500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Vendor Specific Information: Len=78 <?>
    Capabilities: [48] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [d0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [13c] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-00-27-ff-ff-d8-14-2d
    Capabilities: [16c] Power Budgeting <?>
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

i already search the net and suggestion says that i should run this `sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter`then this `sudo modprobe b43`

also check the additional drivers but no b43 driver option that i can enable.

i run `sudo lspci -vnn`but kerner driver in use is still:wl

i checked the broadcom website to check if my wireless model is compatible[14e4:4365] but it says "NO".

is there any work around out there? for this to work?

any help is deeply appreciated

regards

Answer (score 0):

Is there any workaround to get the impossible to work? No. Can we make gold out of lead? No. However, if you'd like to wreck your wireless to find out, the correct procedure is:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Reboot.

Now, if you have some other wireless issue that you thought might be fixed by installing the wrong driver, please tell us about it and we'll be very happy to help.

Comment: Hi Chili555 thank you for a very helpful and sarcastic answer. maybe i should give up on this and try another wireless device. regards

Comment: Isn't your device working as expected with the _wl_ driver? May we address those issues? My answer was intended to be a bit humorous, not sarcastic. If it was sarcastic, I apologize.